# Step in the proof of Girsanov's theroem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In the proof of Girsanov's theorem i see the following: Let $$M_t=e^{ia^{tr}B_t+\frac12||a||^2t}$$ where B is the standard brownian motion and $a\in \mathbb R^d$.

We then know that $$\sup_{t\le T}|M_t|$$ is bounded for all $T\ge0$.

I'm not able to understand this last step, why it is bounded? I only see that $\sup_{t\le T}|M_t|\le\infty$ since $M_t$ is a.s. continuous.

Comment: I don't know anything about Girsanov's theorem. But, I see that $\lvert M_t\rvert = e^{\frac12 \lvert a\rvert^2 t}$. The function in the right-hand side is bounded for $t\in[0, \infty)$. Maybe that's it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: I have written an answer with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a^{\mathrm{tr}}B_t$ is a real number, we have that 
$$\tag{1}
\lvert e^{ia^{\mathrm{tr}}B_t+\frac12\lVert a\rVert^2t}\rvert = e^{\frac12\lVert a\rVert^2t}.  $$ 
We have used a standard property of the complex exponential; 
$$
\lvert e^{x+iy}\rvert = e^{x}, \qquad \forall (x, y)\in \mathbb R^2.$$
Now, 
$$
\sup_{t\in [0, T]} e^{\frac12\lVert a\rVert^2t}= e^{\frac12\lVert a\rVert^2 T}.$$ 
So the left-hand side in (1) is bounded by $e^{\frac12\lVert a\rVert^2 T}$.

Comment: It seems fine, notice that I was asking when $sup|M_t|$ is bounded, namely yours $e^{1/2||a||^2T}$. anyway this seems obvious since could be bounded also by $e^{1/2||a||^2(T+1)}$ i guess

Comment: and are u sure that this hold also when Y not $\in R$ but is a Brownian motion. i thing it change a little bit